# switchMap with forkJoin not showing results

Tags: angular, rxjs

My use case is: I have to get `MeasurementUnit` for each `ProductCategory` by making an api call for each `ProductCategory`.

This is a snippet from one of my service. When `findAll` is subscribed to in a component, it never receives the values. However some values are logged as marked. What am I doing wrong?

Is there an alternative approach to get the same results?

```js
findAll(): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
  return this.http.get<UnresolvedProductCategory[]>(`product-categories/`).pipe(
    tap(categories => console.log(categories)),  // is logged
    switchMap(categories => forkJoin(categories.map(this.resolveCategory.bind(this)))),
    tap(categories => console.log({ finalCategories: categories })) // is not logged
  );
}

resolveCategory(category: UnresolvedProductCategory): Observable<ProductCategory> {
  return this.measurementUnits.findOne(category.measurementUnit).pipe(
    map(measurementUnit => ({ ...category, measurementUnit })),
    tap(category => console.log({ category })) // is logged for each category
  );
}
```

Comment: If all the source observables inside `forkJoin` don't complete, it will never emit. does the `measurementUnits.findOne()` observable actually complete?  If not, maybe add a `take(1)` to it.

Comment: `measurementUnits.findOne` makes another api call using `http.get`. If I'm not wrong, `http.get` completes after returning one value, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it should.  You could try with the `take(1)` to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`forkJoin` will emit only when all source observables have completed.

You could use `combineLatest` instead which will emit once all source observables emit at least once.

---

Alternatively, you could use `take(1)` to ensure that all source observables complete after the first emission:

```
findAll(): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
  return this.http.get<UnresolvedProductCategory[]>(`product-categories/`).pipe(
    tap(categories => console.log(categories)),
    switchMap(categories => forkJoin(categories.map(
      this.resolveCategory.bind(this).pipe(take(1))
    ))),
    tap(categories => console.log({ finalCategories: categories }))
  );
}
```

Comment: Do clarify one more thing, `this.resolveCategory` is actually another api call using `http.get` and it does complete after emitting once (because the values are logged as mentioned in the original snippet). There are also no errors. What gives? It did actually work using `combineLatest`. But why doesn't `forkJoin` work?